# Replace characters in a string with their HTML coding

Tags: php, html, str-replace

I need to replace characters in a string with their HTML coding.

Ex. The "quick" brown fox, jumps over the lazy (dog).

I need to replace the quotations with the & quot; and replace the brakets with & #40; and & #41;

I have tried str_replace, but I can only get 1 character to be replaced.  Is there a way to replace multiple characters using str_replace?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have taken a look at htmlentities().  I see where I can get the double quotes converted, but what about returns - \n and ().  I am not sure how to plug those into the htmlentities.

Comment: Hmm.. that sounds difficult. I'm not sure if there is a specific kind of function which would be better than using `str_replace()` and `htmlentities()`.

Comment: the question is: why do you feel you need to convert bracket characters to entities? there's nothing special about them.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the function `htmlentities()`.

Have a look at the [Manual](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: The issue with htmlentities is that it doesn't convert `(` to `&#40;` like the OP wants.

Answer (score 4):

PHP has a number of functions to deal with this sort of thing:

Firstly, [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars).

But as you already found out, they won't deal with `(` and `)` characters, because these are not characters that ever need to be rendered as entities in HTML. I guess the question is why you want to convert these specific characters to entities? I can't really see a good reason for doing it.

If you really do need to do it, `str_replace()` will do multiple string replacements, using arrays in both the search and replace paramters:

```
$output = str_replace(array('(',')'), array('&#40','&#41'), $input);
```

You can also use the [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/strtr) function in a similar way:

```
$conversions = array('('=>'&#40;', ')'=>'&#41;');
$output = strtr($conversions, $input);
```

Either of these would do the trick for you. Again, I don't know why you'd want to though, because there's nothing special about `(` and `)` brackets in this context.

While you're looking into the above, you might also want to look up [`get_html_translation_table()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php), which returns an array of entity conversions as used in `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`, in a format suitable for use with `strtr()`. You could load that array and add the extra characters to it before running the conversion; this would allow you to convert all normal entity characters as well as the same time.

I would point out that if you serve your page with the UTF8 character set, you won't need to convert any characters to entities (except for the HTML reserved characters `<`, `>` and `&`). This may be an alternative solution for you.

You also asked in a separate comment about converting line feeds. These can be converted with PHP's [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/nl2br) function, but could also be done using `str_replace()` or `strtr()`, so could be added to a conversion array with everything else.